# How can I build a compact matrix from a sparse dataframe?

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing three columns 1st: origin interactor (org), 2nd: value of interaction (rsq) 3rd: target interactor(tgt), which look like this (example) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yIBU.png), i would like to convert it into a compact matrix like this(example)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WU6LB.png), the dataframe that I am using is really big, (36791 elements) in order to do that, I coded the following:

```html
the_list  <- data.frame(org,rsq,tgt)

a  <- length(org)
b  <- length(tgt)

str(the_list)
#output matrix
dm = matrix( nrow= a, ncol= b, dim = list(org, tgt))

for (i in 1:nrow(the_list)){ #iterate thorugh lines of input file
  
  dm[match(the_list[i,1],rownames(dm)), match(the_list[i,3],colnames(dm))] = the_list[i,2]
                                                      
}
dm
```

I would really appreciate your support in that, since, as you might guess, I have basically no experience in that.
Thank you so much
Alfredo

Comment: I forgot to add, when I run the code above, R crashes, and of course nothing works, I don't know if is a problem of dimensions of the datasets, or something else.

Answer (score 0):

If there are already all expressions in the "target" column, you could do the following.
Corresponding to the column names of your pictures provided:

```
library("reshape2")    
the_list2 <- dcast(the_list,target~origin,value.var="value")
```

But I do not know how it long it takes if the original data frame is becoming large.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `dplyr` and `tidyr`, but you might run in to some problems if your data doesn't look exactly like you have described it.

Firstly let's create your input data:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

start <- tibble(origin = c(rep("a", 9), rep("b", 8)),
                value = paste0("x", 1:17),
                target = c("a", "b", "c", "e", "f", "l", "z", "s", "n", "a",
                               "e", "f", "j", "k", "t", "l", "s"))
```

Then transform it in to something that resembles what you're looking for:

```
end <- start %>% 
    spread(origin, value)
```

This will give:

```
end

# A tibble: 12 x 3
   target     a     b
*   <chr> <chr> <chr>
1       a    x1   x10
2       b    x2  <NA>
3       c    x3  <NA>
4       e    x4   x11
5       f    x5   x12
6       j  <NA>   x13
7       k  <NA>   x14
8       l    x6   x16
9       n    x9  <NA>
10      s    x8   x17
11      t  <NA>   x15
12      z    x7  <NA>
```

As per your original question, this isn't quite what you were after as the new `target` column is missing some values (e.g. `d` and 'g', plus others).

In the absense of any actual data from yourself, the best I can do is to manually create those missing rows (simple enough in your case as they're just letters)

```
tibble(target = letters) %>% 
    left_join(end)

# A tibble: 26 x 3
   target     a     b
    <chr> <chr> <chr>
1       a    x1   x10
2       b    x2  <NA>
3       c    x3  <NA>
4       d  <NA>  <NA>
5       e    x4   x11
6       f    x5   x12
7       g  <NA>  <NA>
8       h  <NA>  <NA>
9       i  <NA>  <NA>
10      j  <NA>   x13
# ... with 16 more rows
```

In the case of your actual data, you'll need either to make sure that your starting data contains all the `target` values that you're interested in, or (like I did) create them manually and join your result to them.

Even on a large data set, this should be fast in `dplyr` and `tidyr`.